# Is any morphism composition of smooth and radicial morphisms generically?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Is it true that for any proper dominant morphism $\pi:X \rightarrow Y$, there is an open set $U\subset Y$ such that $\pi|_U$ is a composition of smooth morphisms and radicial morphisms (assuming $X$ is regular, also can assume that $X$ and $Y$ are of finite type over a finite field)?

Comment: I'm confused, do you mean a *dense nonempty open set $U \subseteq X$* instead of a subset of $Y$?

Comment: Yes, I do mean dense, nonempty open set. (Nonempty is the hard one I guess).

But I today learnt that this is not possible. (Need to look at example myself, before I say more).

However, in that case I will be happy with a "radicial modification" that is a morphism $X'\rightarrow Y'$ satisfying the property in question such that we have maps $X\rightarrow X'$ and $Y\rightarrow Y'$ radicial, making the diagram commute.

(Or even if it is $X'\rightarrow X$ and $Y'\rightarrow Y$, with the same property).

Comment: Ok. So the example seems to be incorrect, the original question stands.

Comment: Valbhav -- You still need to make $U$ an open subset of $X$ rather than $Y$, otherwise just take $X$ to be any singular variety and take $Y$ to be a point.

Comment: In your comment above, you seem to be allowing radicial maps to and from things.  What if the maps go the other way, i.e. can we assume that $X$ and $Y$ are reduced?

Comment: Karl -- yes you can assume radicial map in either directions. (My reason of interest is that they are cohomologically dead). Jason -- you are right, I forgot to mention that X has to be regular. Editing the question to reflect that. – Vaibhav 1 min ago 


Comment: Vaibhav, I just want to be sure, you really want $U$ to be an open set of $Y$ and not of $X$?  I think it's not true in that case.

Comment: Yes, I want Y. With X it is easy.